# GET http://localhost/water_purifier-main/admin/public/images/products/cat.png 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, html

this is products.php

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');
require_once('admin/scripts/ManageProducts.php');

$manageProducts = new ManageProducts($conn);
$products = $manageProducts->get();
?>

<?php include 'component/header.php'; ?>

<div class="container-fluid products big-padding px-3 bg-gray">
    <div class="container-xl">
        <div class="section-title row mb-4  pt-5 mt-4">
            <h2 class="fs-1 fw-bold  text-dark-blue m-0">Our Products</h2>
            <p class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget
                dolor ipsum
                dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- owl-carousel  -->
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme row" data-aos="fade-up">
            <?php if (!empty($products)) : ?>
                <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
                    <div class="item col-lg-11 mb-4">
                        <a href="contact.php">
                            <div class="product bg-white p-4 text-center shadow-md">
                                <img class="mah-150" src="<?= $product['productImage']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['productName']; ?>">
                                <div class="d-inline-block">
                                    <h4 class="fw-bolder fs-5 mt-4"><?= $product['productName']; ?></h4>
                                    <span class="fw-bolder fs-4"><?= $product['productPrice']; ?></span> <span
                                        class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">₹5,000</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-inline-block mt-3">
                                    <button class="btn blue-btn px-5">Buy Now</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p>No products found.</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include 'component/footer.php'; ?>
```

this is ManageProducts.php

```
<?php

class ManageProducts {

    private $conn;
    private $productsTable = "products";
    private $imageFolder = "admin/public/images/products/";

    public function __construct($conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function validate($productName, $productPrice, $productImage) {
        $error = false;
        $errMsg = '';

        if (empty($productName) || empty($productPrice) || empty($productImage)) {
            $errMsg = "Product name, price, and image are required";
            $error = true;
        }

        return array(
            "error" => $error,
            "errMsg" => $errMsg
        );
    }

    public function create($productName, $productPrice, $productImage) {
        $validate = $this->validate($productName, $productPrice, $productImage);
        $success = false;
    
        if (!$validate['error']) {
            // Ensure the destination directory exists
            if (!file_exists($this->imageFolder)) {
                mkdir($this->imageFolder, 0755, true); // Create directory recursively
            }
    
            $destination = $this->imageFolder . basename($_FILES['productImage']['name']);
    
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], $destination)) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->productsTable . " (productName, productPrice, productImage) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    
                // Bind parameters
                $stmt->bind_param("sds", $productName, $productPrice, $destination);
    
                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    $success = true;
                } else {
                    $validate['errMsg'] = "Error executing query: " . $stmt->error;
                }
                $stmt->close();
            } else {
                $validate['errMsg'] = "Error uploading image";
            }
        }
    
        return array(
            'errMsg' => $validate['errMsg'],
            'success' => $success
        );
    }
    
    
    

    public function get() {
        $data = array();

        $query = "SELECT id, productName, productPrice, productImage FROM " . $this->productsTable;
        $result = $this->conn->query($query);

        if ($result) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            $result->free();
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function getById($id) {
        $data = array();

        $query = "SELECT productName, productPrice, productImage FROM " . $this->productsTable . " WHERE id=?";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function updateById($id, $productName, $productPrice, $productImage) {
        $validate = $this->validate($productName, $productPrice, $productImage);
        $success = false;

        if (!$validate['error']) {
            $query = "UPDATE " . $this->productsTable . " SET productName = ?, productPrice = ?, productImage = ? WHERE id = ?";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("sdsi", $productName, $productPrice, $productImage, $id);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $success = true;
            } else {
                $validate['errMsg'] = "Error executing query: " . $stmt->error;
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }

        return array(
            'errMsg' => $validate['errMsg'],
            'success' => $success
        );
    }

    public function deleteById($id) {
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->productsTable . " WHERE id = ?";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is form.php

```
<?php
require_once '../database.php';
require_once('scripts/ManageProducts.php');

$manageProducts = new ManageProducts($conn);
$msg = '';
$errMsg = '';
$product = ['productName' => '', 'productPrice' => '', 'productImage' => ''];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    $productName = $_POST['productName'];
    $productPrice = $_POST['productPrice'];

    // File upload handling
    if(isset($_FILES['productImage']) && $_FILES['productImage']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $productImage = $_FILES['productImage']['name'];
        $tempName = $_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'];
    } else {
        $errMsg = 'Product image is required';
    }

    if (empty($errMsg)) {
        if ($_POST['action'] === 'create') {
            $create = $manageProducts->create($productName, $productPrice, $tempName);
            if ($create['success']) {
                $msg = "Product saved successfully";
            } else {
                $errMsg = $create['errMsg'];
            }
        } elseif ($_POST['action'] === 'update') {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $update = $manageProducts->updateById($id, $productName, $productPrice, $tempName);
            if ($update['success']) {
                $msg = "Product updated successfully";
            } else {
                $errMsg = $update['errMsg'];
            }
        }
    }
}

// Fetch product details if editing
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $product = $manageProducts->getById($id);
}
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="mb-4">Product Form</h3>
        <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-end">
        <a href="dashboard.php?page=manage-products-list" class="btn btn-success">Products List</a>
    </div>
</div>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?= isset($_GET['id']) ? 'update' : 'create'; ?>"> <!-- Ensure action field is set -->
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ''; ?>">
    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productName" value="<?= $product['productName'] ?? ''; ?>">
        <p class="text-danger"><?php echo $errMsg; ?></p>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productPrice" value="<?= $product['productPrice'] ?? ''; ?>">
        <p class="text-danger"><?php echo $errMsg; ?></p>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="productImage">
        <p class="text-danger"><?php echo $errMsg; ?></p>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><?= isset($_GET['id']) ? 'Update' : 'Save'; ?></button>

    <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) : ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">Delete</button>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

This is table.php

```
<?php
require_once '../database.php';
require_once('scripts/ManageProducts.php');

$manageProducts = new ManageProducts($conn);
$products = $manageProducts->get();
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="mb-4">Products List</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-end">
        <a href="dashboard.php?page=manage-products-form" class="btn btn-success">Add New</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive-sm">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.N</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if (!empty($products)) : ?>
                <?php foreach ($products as $sn => $product) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $sn + 1; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="<?= $product['productImage']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['productName']; ?>" style="max-width: 100px;">
                        </td>
                        <td><?= $product['productName']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $product['productPrice']; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="dashboard.php?page=manage-products-form&id=<?= $product['id']; ?>" class="text-success">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <form method="post" action="scripts/ajax/DeleteProducts.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $product['id']; ?>">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link text-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product?');">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">No products found</td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

can anyone help me with these cant load the images after i try to upload the image from admin panel  i also gave full access to the folder still its not loading  in the admin panel its showing the images but from the products.php its not showing